# Unpack binary file contents; modify value; then pack contents to new binary file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a binary file and limited knowledge of the structure of the file.  I'd like to unpack the contents of the file, make a change to a value, and then re-pack the modified contents into a new binary file.  If I can complete the unpacking successfully, I certainly can modify one of the values; and then I believe I will be able to handle the re-packing to create a new binary file.  However, I am having trouble completing the unpacking.  This is what I have so far

```
image = None
one = two = three = four = five = 0
with open(my_file, 'rb') as fil:
    one = struct.unpack('i', fil.read(4))[0]
    two = struct.unpack('i', fil.read(4))[0]
    three = struct.unpack('d', fil.read(8))[0]
    four = struct.unpack('d', fil.read(8))[0]
    five = struct.unpack('iiii', fil.read(16))
    image = fil.read(920)
```

When I set a breakpoint below the section of code displayed above, I can see that the type of the `image` variable above is `<class 'bytes'>`.  The type of `fil` is `<class 'io.BufferedReader'>`.  How can I unpack the data in this `image` variable?

Comment: A you sure that you need to unpack all file? You can read file into `bytearray`, modify some fields and write it after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendation from @Stanislav directly led me to the solution to this problem.  Ultimately, I did not need struct unpack/pack to reach my goal. The code below roughly illustrates the solution.

```
with open(my_file, 'rb') as fil:
   data = bytearray(fil.read())
   mylist = list(data)
   mylist[8] = mylist[8] + 2  #modify some fields
   mylist[9] = mylist[9] + 2
   mylist[16] = mylist[16] + 3
   data = bytearray(mylist)
   another_file = open("other_file.bin", "wb")
   another_file.write(data)
   another_file.close()
```